# How to get the start/end of the current buffer info with emacs/elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following code that runs figlet that has input as a range.
How can I modify this code to check if b or e is not specified, make b to the start of the current buffer, and e end of the current buffer?

```
(defun figlet-region (&optional b e) 
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region b e "/opt/local/bin/figlet" (current-buffer) t)
  (comment-region (mark) (point)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x") 'figlet-region)
```

### ADDED

Sean helped me to get an answer to this question

```
(defun figlet-region (&optional b e) 
  (interactive)
  (let ((b (if mark-active (min (point) (mark)) (point-min)))
        (e (if mark-active (max (point) (mark)) (point-max))))
   (shell-command-on-region b e "/opt/local/bin/figlet" (current-buffer) t)
  (comment-region (mark) (point))))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x") 'figlet-region)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
(defun figlet-region (&optional b e) 
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region
   (or b (point-min))
   (or e (point-max))
   "/opt/local/bin/figlet" (current-buffer) t)
  (comment-region (mark) (point)))
```

But note that `b` and `e` will always be set when this command is run interactively.

You could also do this:

```
(require 'cl)

(defun* figlet-region (&optional (b (point-min)) (e (point-max)))
  # your original function body here
    )
```

EDIT:

So I guess you mean you want to be able to run the command interactively even if the region is not active?  Then maybe this will work for you:

```
(defun figlet-region ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((b (if mark-active (min (point) (mark)) (point-min)))
        (e (if mark-active (max (point) (mark)) (point-max))))
    # ... rest of your original function body ...
      ))
```

Comment: I tried, but it seems that when I don't make any region, point-min and point-max points to correct position (start and end of the buffer).

Comment: If the positions are correct, then what's the problem?  I don't understand.

Comment: I tried to say 'point-min doesn't point to the start of the buffer', and 'point-max' doesn't point to the end of the buffer. As I mentioned, when I make any region, nothing happens.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on exactly what you want to accomplish, but I added another possible interpretation above...

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
(unless b (setq b (point-min)))
(unless e (setq e (point-max)))
```

Comment: I get "The mark is not set now, so there is no region", when I just open a doc and do "C-c C-k".